# Using jQuery noConflict() with script.aculo.us

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, debugging

I have a site using a "widget" (from http://healcode.com) that includes the [script.aculo.us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script.aculo.us) JavaScript library. The problem is that the site I'm building is on WordPress, so there's the classic `jQuery` vs `script.aculo.us` conflict.

I know that I need to run jQuery in `.noConflict()` mode, but I must be getting the syntax wrong. When I assign the `$` to jQuery `.noConflict` as follows, it still shuts down the script.aculo.us functions:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function () {

    //#nav-main dropdown effects

    $('#nav-main ul li').hoverIntent(function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideDown('900'); },
            function(){
                $(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideUp('500');
        });
}); // end document.ready
```

I know that I am assigning the `$` to jQuery in `.noConflict()` mode, and I assume that script.aculo.us (which loads via a widget in the main body, therefore AFTER jQuery) is trying to re-assign the `$` back to script.aculo.us.

How can I assign the `$` to jQuery in a way that the later-loaded script.aculo.us library won't conflict? I've already tried the following without any success (the following code causes script.aculo.us to work, but jQuery to fail):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    //#nav-main dropdown effects

    jQuery('#nav-main ul li').hoverIntent(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideDown('900'); },
            function(){
                jQuery(this).find('.dropdown').stop(true,true).slideUp('500');
        });
}); // end document.ready
```

**EDIT**

The debug console output for the above code is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' (anonymous function)` so the document.ready fails because it's assigned to jQuery, which is somehow not loading properly...

**EDIT 2**

Both of the 2 (at the time of this update) answers posted below do nothing to address the issue I'm struggling with. Perhaps they are technically correct, but they do not address my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me so that I can have jQuery and [script.aculo.us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script.aculo.us)/Prototype working well together. Credit goes to [codeimpossible](http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/) for this lifesaver!

Instead of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Code to run on DOM ready

}); // End document.ready
```

Try this:

```
( function($) {

    // Code to run on DOM ready

} )( jQuery ); // End document.ready
```

Comment: Thanks @Marty McGee - I posted this so long ago that I haven't seen it for years - but your method is my default nowadays, so I'll mark this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution VERY surprising!

First of all, using the `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` mode did not work.

Second, calling `jQuery.noConflict();` at the head did not work.

The method that did work was this one: http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/

Oddly, the [Coda Slider 2.0 plugin](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) does not automatically do `noConflict` so it turned out that **IN ADDITION** to the problems listed above, I needed to wrap that plugin in `.noConflict();` as well. Shout out the the author of the blog post, not sure why other `noConflict();` calling methods didn't work, but I'm glad I found the post.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) right back to `$` doesn't do anything.

Either assign jQuery to a different variable:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Or don't assign it to anything:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: Both of those proposals still cause jQuery to conflict (therefore having scriptaculous take precedence and jQuery functions failing to execute).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what actually happens? `jQuery` should refer to jQuery no mater what (unless you pass `true` to .noConflict).

Comment: I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
(anonymous function)` so the `document.ready` fails because it's assigned to jQuery, which is somehow not loading properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="url to jquery"></script>
<script type="javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="url to scriptaculous"></script>
```

Comment: That's a good thought although it doesn't work :( ... the idea of including it alone in the document header (since it's WordPress there's a chance of the system including other jQuery dependent plugins) is something I didn't think of...