# jQuery conflict with script.aculo.us

Tags: jquery, scriptaculous

I include jQuery 1.10, [script.aculo.us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script.aculo.us) and [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) in the same file. It shows the error:

> Cannot call method 'click' of undefined

I suspect it is due to library conflict, so I did this:

```
JQuery(document).ready(function() {...
```

and move script.aculo.us after all other scripts. Unfortunately it shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined

The solution in *[Using jQuery noConflict() with script.aculo.us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524700)* doesn't work for me.

My code

```
{literal}
    <script src="include/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="include/js/general.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        JQuery(document).ready(function() { ...
    </script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="include/scriptaculous/prototype.js"></script>
    <script src="include/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{/literal}
```

`literal` is Smarty tag.

Comment: 1.10 is the latest of JQuery 1.x. It is not too old.

Comment: The `J` is lower case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `JQuery`, but the J is lower case, so use `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`...